# Can you edit normal .py scripts interactively in jupyterlab?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I'm thinking similar to atom with the hydrogen plugin?

When doing data science in Python I tend to get stuck in a "first create it in jupyter notebook, then re-create it in an actual python script so we can go into production". Using Atom i've been able to just create the code directly in a python script, but still have the great interactive features of jupyter.

I was really hoping that jupyterlab would be similar, but as far as i can tell, you only get the interactive features in the python notebooks and not in python scripts?

Answer (score 2):

**To write/save**

```
%%writefile myfile.py
```

write/save cell contents into myfile.py (use -a to append). Another alias: %%file myfile.py

**To run**

```
%run myfile.py
```

run myfile.py and output results in the current cell

**To load/import**

```
%load myfile.py
```

load "import" myfile.py into the current cell

**For more magic and help**

```
%lsmagic
```

**list all the other cool cell magic commands.**

```
%COMMAND-NAME?
```

for help on how to use a certain command. i.e. %run?

Comment: Those are some cool workarounds, but still a rather un-appealing workflow in my opinion, but looks like atom/hydrogen combo is my only option currently if i want to edit a .py file directly and still have the dynamic alt-enter to run the line i'm in.

Answer (score 0):

You might like using the Spyder IDE for this.  You can use it to edit and execute jupyter notebooks and python scripts:
https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/plugins/notebook.html